# How to get inputname of variable passed into function through cellfun?

Tags: matlab, function, variable-names

I know that the custom function `myfun` outputs the variable names that are passed to it using the [`inputname`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html) command.

However, when I pass variables through a `cellfun` the `inputname` command ceases to work, as shown below (where I am passing in the variable names `j`, `lat`, and `lon`. Here, it just somehow outputs all the variables as 'x'.

```
>> cellfun(@(x)myfun(x, y), {j, lat, lon}, 'UniformOutput', false)

First calling variable is "x".
First calling variable is "x".
First calling variable is "x".

ans = 
    'x'    'x'    'x'
```

And if I try:

```
cellfun(@myfun, {j}, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

I get:

```
First calling variable is "".

ans = 
    {''}
```

I'm doing this because I'm creating a bunch of plots with a function, and would like all the plots auto-labeled with the variable name of the variable I'm passing into the plots.

Comment: Instead of showing us 10 different ways to call your home-built function, why don't you show us that function instead? You should always try to give a minimum example that shows your problem, this question can be asked much better.

Comment: Okay, I totally revamped the question now.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend depending on variable names too much. It is nice to do this for a quick evaluation, but think twice before building it into a program. If you want to combine textual information with values consider using a `struct` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You lose the connection between the name of the variable you pass and `inputname` in this scenario. The only solution I see is to send the name of the variable as an additional argument to `myfun`. You need to extract the names using a separate function like this:

```
function [values, names] = getNames(varargin)
values = varargin;
names = cell(size(varargin));
for iArg = 1:nargin
    names{iArg} = inputname(iArg);
end
end
```

Then your code should look like this

```
[values, names] = getNames(j,lat,lon);
cellfun(@(x,n)myfun(x,y,n),values,names,'UniformOutput',false);
```

Now the third argument passed to `myfun` contains the name of its first argument.
**Update**:
This means you need to edit `myfun` to accept a third argument as the name of the variable instead of using `inputname`.

Comment: @EitanT Have you edited `myFun` to take the third argument as the name of the first argument instead of using `inputname`?

Comment: @EitanT The point is that you lose the name of variables when you create the cell array `{j, lat, lon}`. So the names should be captured before that. AND, probably `myfun` does some thing more, it would be pointless if the only thing `myfun` does is returning the name of it's argument.

Comment: `myfun` is probably copied from the example [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html). If you are allowed to modify `myfun`, your workarounds seem pointless to me. You can print the variable names separately, and leave the rest of the calculations in `myfun`.

Comment: Unless the `myfun` function includes the plotting part that needs the name of the variables. I don't think the priniting of the variable names is the goal. They seem to be used for debugging.

Comment: Unless `myfun` IS the plotting function which you cannot modify.

Comment: OP says custom function, not built-in MATLAB function

Comment: This is due to my edit, to make it clear that in the current example `myfun` utilizes `inputname`. In the general case, I infer that `myfun` can be anything.